# elasticsearch - improve query performance

Tags: performance, elasticsearch, query-performance

I am using a hosted elasticsearch cloud with 2 indexes each has 50,000 documents and one of this size is around 300MB (on this we are applying search) and another one is of 50MB (on this we are applying suggestion) and also added query caching to both the indexes.

1. index with size of 300MB (using for search)

   - This query is taking 1.2s to 1.5s response time
     Settings JSON

```
{
  "index.blocks.read_only_allow_delete": "false",
  "index.priority": "1",
  "index.query.default_field": [
    "*"
  ],
  "index.write.wait_for_active_shards": "1",
  "index.refresh_interval": "9000s",
  "index.requests.cache.enable": "true",
  "index.analysis.analyzer.edge_ngram_analyzer.filter": [
    "lowercase"
  ],
  "index.analysis.analyzer.edge_ngram_analyzer.tokenizer": "edge_ngram_tokenizer",
  "index.analysis.analyzer.keyword_analyzer.filter": [
    "lowercase",
    "asciifolding",
    "trim"
  ],
  "index.analysis.analyzer.keyword_analyzer.char_filter": [],
  "index.analysis.analyzer.keyword_analyzer.type": "custom",
  "index.analysis.analyzer.keyword_analyzer.tokenizer": "keyword",
  "index.analysis.analyzer.singular_plural_analyzer.type": "snowball",
  "index.analysis.analyzer.edge_ngram_search_analyzer.tokenizer": "lowercase",
  "index.analysis.tokenizer.edge_ngram_tokenizer.token_chars": [
    "letter"
  ],
  "index.analysis.tokenizer.edge_ngram_tokenizer.min_gram": "2",
  "index.analysis.tokenizer.edge_ngram_tokenizer.type": "edge_ngram",
  "index.analysis.tokenizer.edge_ngram_tokenizer.max_gram": "5",
  "index.number_of_replicas": "1"
}
```

2. index with the size of 50MB (using for the suggestion)

   - This query is taking 0.5s  to 0.6s response time.

Setting JSON

```
{
  "index.blocks.read_only_allow_delete": "false",
  "index.priority": "1",
  "index.query.default_field": [
    "*"
  ],
  "index.write.wait_for_active_shards": "1",
  "index.refresh_interval": "90000s",
  "index.requests.cache.enable": "true",
  "index.analysis.analyzer.edge_ngram_analyzer.filter": [
    "lowercase"
  ],
  "index.analysis.analyzer.edge_ngram_analyzer.tokenizer": "edge_ngram_tokenizer",
  "index.analysis.analyzer.keyword_analyzer.filter": [
    "lowercase",
    "asciifolding",
    "trim"
  ],
  "index.analysis.analyzer.keyword_analyzer.char_filter": [],
  "index.analysis.analyzer.keyword_analyzer.type": "custom",
  "index.analysis.analyzer.keyword_analyzer.tokenizer": "keyword",
  "index.analysis.analyzer.singular_plural_analyzer.type": "snowball",
  "index.analysis.analyzer.edge_ngram_search_analyzer.tokenizer": "lowercase",
  "index.analysis.tokenizer.edge_ngram_tokenizer.token_chars": [
    "letter"
  ],
  "index.analysis.tokenizer.edge_ngram_tokenizer.min_gram": "2",
  "index.analysis.tokenizer.edge_ngram_tokenizer.type": "edge_ngram",
  "index.analysis.tokenizer.edge_ngram_tokenizer.max_gram": "5",
  "index.number_of_replicas": "0"
}
```

I want to increase response time for both the queries.

Right now system/elasticsearch cloud configurations images link added below.

[image: inline image]

Can you please help me to increase the performance of queries.

Comment: Welcome to stof, please provide as much as relevant information you think is required to solve your issue, hint: you are asking for improving your search query performance but there is no search query provided in your question.

Comment: Sorry to inconvenience @OpsterESNinja. I checked it and the network was slowing down the query response from elasticsearch cloud.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out and solved my issue by installing elasticsearch to my local server and removed the network dependency.

The issue was remote elasticsearch cloud and slower network. Now, both queries giving me a response within 15ms to 20ms.

Comment: n/w latency shouldn't be this much

Comment: I was also not believing this. elasticsearch configured/hosted in US-east and I was accessing it from India. after I hosted it locally with same configuration it works amazing.

Comment: Still, have done this cross-region multiple times but still its not so costly

Comment: What would be the issue according to you?

Comment: can u just ping those servers from local and provide response time

Comment: It's giving me around 1.2s to 1.3s

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206861/discussion-between-opster-es-ninja-and-tejas-ambalia).